# Intersection of ideals of ring sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, $A=k[T]$, $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$, and $\mathfrak a_n=AT^n\subset A$ $(n\in \mathbb N)$. Why do the intersection of the ideals of sheaf of rings $\tilde A$, i.e. $\bigcap \tilde{\mathfrak a}_n$ is the same as $\tilde{A}_{D(T)}$? And why it is not a quasicoherent $\tilde A$-module?

Comment: What is $\tilde{A}$ at here? You mean $\tilde{A}_{D(T)}$ as the sheaf at the distinguished open subset $D(T)$?

Comment: Sorry. It was said in that $\tilde Ã$ is a sheaf of rings. And I believe the author means $\tilde A_{D(T)}$ to be the sheaf at the distinguished open subset $D(T)$ as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to do this as an exercise for myself. The second part I cannot do because I do not know.

Let $A=k[T]$ and ideals $a_{i}=\langle T^{i}\rangle$ as you suggested. Then the sheaf at the distinguished open subset $D_{(a_{i})}$ is $A_{a_{i}}=k[T,T^{-i}]$. You have the obviously inclusion relationship $a_{i}\subset a_{i-1}\cdots \langle T\rangle$, therefore $V(a_{i})\supset V(a_{j}),D(a_{i})\subset D(a_{j}), \forall i\le j$. Finally the sheaf at $D(T)$ is simply the Laurent series ring $k[T,T^{-1}]$.

We need to show that the stalk we get by taking limit over the sequence of open sets $D_{(a_{i})}$ is the sheaf over $D(T)$. Note the restriction map $D_{(a_{j})}\rightarrow D_{(a_{i})}$ corresponds to the inclusion map $k[T,T^{-j}]\rightarrow k[T,T^{-i}]$ because essentially we have $A_{f}\rightarrow A_{g}$ if $D(g)\subset D(f)$. Therefore after taking the direct limit we recovered the Laurent series ring as desired. I do not think the "intersection" thing makes much sense unless you mean intersection of open sets.